# Restarting DevStack services - Safest way

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am using devstack setup in my development environment.

I need the safest way to restarting a particular service in Devstack.

I have tried all the possible way:

I tried the screen -r command  it simply shows an error message as follows:

```
root@devstack:/opt/devstack# screen -r
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

Then I have tried to open the screen as stack user, then it is showing the error as follows:

```
stack@devstack:/opt/devstack$ screen -r
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/43' - please check.
```

So that I went with the final option root@devstack:/opt/devstack# ./rejoin-stack.sh

But in this case, after this command, I am getting the error as follows when I am accessing the devstack horizon.

```
root@devstack:/opt/devstack# ./rejoin-stack.sh
```

Each and every horizon page I am getting an error as above.

I can see that in screen there are many errors in many services, Someone let me know the easy and safest way for restarting of services.

Answer (score 0):

`rejoin` command is the fastest and safest way of restarting, but restart doesn't mean that `reinstalling the whole environment`. you must protect the configuration of the environment. Most probably you have some problem with environment configuration and `rejoin` doesn't solve your problem...